# Recover failed sonar upgrade (missing table)

Tags: migration, sonarqube

Due a backup issue the migration from sonar 3.5.1 to 3.7 got messed up a bit. Now some tables are missing but the migration is done.

Is there some way I can rerun the db migration to create the missing tables ?

Note I have so far only seen one problem and it shows in the log as:

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'sonar.issue_filters' doesn't exist
```

when I show the issues page or the issues drilldown. And I see that table is created in war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/db/migrate/411_create_issue_filters.rb

So based on the info there it seems I could create that one manually directly in sql but is there a better safe way to recover this migration ? (as I suspect the issue_filters is not the only problem)

Using MySQL for the db.

Comment: Which DB are you using ? Could you attach to this thread the log file of the failing migration from version 3.5.1 to version 3.7 ?

Comment: @FreddyMallet-SonarSource It was not the migration itself that caused the missing tables but a failed attempt to restore an earlier db from backup.

Comment: @FreddyMallet-SonarSource Any tip on recreating missing tables ? Still using this half-broken db since we don't want to lose whats there.

Comment: One possible way to do that is to : create a fully new SonarQube DB schema, to ask SonarQube to create the structure just by starting the server and to migrate data from your own schema to the new one. But in that case you must select the SonarQube version the closer to the version of your current SonarQube DB.

Comment: I made a try, but I still got errors when trying to start - so as I have no more time to spend on it I started over with a fresh db. So no history left but at least it's back in a fully working state.